# Confused about HTTP in Wireshark

Tags: networking, http, wireshark, packet

I'm currently using Wireshark and I'm trying to fill out a table
that what's the Packet Number for the HTTP request and HTTP Response. I've used the filter in Wireshark however, I'm not sure what packet is the right one.

How do I know which is the right HTTP Request and HTTP Response? [Image of packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZyOp.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It will be easier to help you if you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1488625/edit) your post to include a link to the packet capture instead of an image. "I'm not sure what packet is the right one." => Can you provide more context in your question as to which packet the "right one" is?

Comment: Do you want to set the answer as solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have filtered for `http.request`. Therefore you only see HTTP requests (and some protocols that build on HTTP requests). All lines with `GET` are http requests.

If you want to see both requests and responses, you need a different filter, for example just `http`.